# laravel 5 model method not working

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table with rows with column contain string `"this\dIs\dA\dString"`

```
$callPlans = CustomerCallPlan::where('customer_id', $customer->id)->get();
```

I get the values like above and expected string 'thisXIsXAXString'
as you guess I replace '\d' with 'X'. to do this I use method below inside model class.

```
class CustomerCallPlan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'customer_callplan';

    protected $fillable = [
        'template',
        'priority',
        'customer_id',
        'strip',
        'add_number',
        'actiontype',
        'data'
    ];

    public function getNumbertemplateAttribute() {
        return str_replace('\d', 'X', $this->attributes['template']);
    }
}
```

But somehow data comes to model without replaced.. what might be cause this ??

Comment: Where and when are you calling `getNumbertemplateAttribute()`?

Comment: good question I never called it. I think this method being call for every requestr with laravel eloquient object, model class(CustomerCallPlan)

Comment: How does the laravel eloquent object knows that it should call this method? I suppose there is a mechanism in laravel for that. Either you have to specify somewhere which function should be called on every model request or the function name is build after a specific syntax. For the latter I think your function name does not look like such a thing and for the first one a kind a configuration is missing.

Comment: This is called an accessor and it'll automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value. This takes the camel cased name of your field so make sure it's correct. If it's **number_template** your method should be called `getNumberTemplateAttribute()`.

Comment: I simply changed method name to 'getTemplateAttribute' and it works :). Fallen thank you I can accept your answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an accessor and it'll automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value. The method name should be the camel cased name of the column you wish to access, prepended by **get** and followed by **Attribute**, for example `getColumnNameAttribute()` will take the column **colum_name**.